# How do I understand the Vuex docs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

[Here's](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typing-store-property-in-vue-component) the link to a paragraph from the Vuex docs:

> To do so, declare custom typings for Vue's `ComponentCustomProperties` by adding a declaration file in your project folder:

How am I supposed to know what a declaration file is?

Are they referring to making a shim file? Is there a place where they describe these terms and what they mean?

Comment: Read the example: `vuex.d.ts`. They assume you're familiar with TS to use it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html.

Comment: If you mean shim.d.ts that presents in some boilerplate projects then yes, if you have it, you need a similar one. Make sure you did everything for it to be included by TS, if there's an explicit mention of "shim" in configs (this could be necessary depending on the setup), another .d.ts needs to be treated in the same way